# What do these LogCat errors mean? My program crashes

Tags: android, logcat

```
07-03 23:59:01.067: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
07-03 23:59:01.067: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
07-03 23:59:01.067: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
07-03 23:59:01.067: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
07-03 23:59:28.297: ERROR/BatteryService(60): usbOnlinePath not found
07-03 23:59:28.307: ERROR/BatteryService(60): batteryVoltagePath not found
07-03 23:59:28.307: ERROR/BatteryService(60): batteryTemperaturePath not found
07-03 23:59:28.407: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(60): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
07-03 23:59:39.097: ERROR/EventHub(60): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-03 23:59:39.137: ERROR/EventHub(60): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
07-03 23:59:39.777: ERROR/System(60): Failure starting core service
07-03 23:59:39.777: ERROR/System(60): java.lang.SecurityException
07-03 23:59:39.777: ERROR/System(60):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-03 23:59:39.777: ERROR/System(60):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
07-03 23:59:39.777: ERROR/System(60):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
07-03 23:59:39.777: ERROR/System(60):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:176)
07-03 23:59:39.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(60): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
07-04 00:00:00.400: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)
07-04 00:00:01.147: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
07-04 00:00:01.227: ERROR/MediaPlayer(60): Unable to to create media player
07-04 00:00:06.315: ERROR/ActivityThread(104): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
07-04 00:00:11.615: ERROR/ActivityThread(104): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
07-04 00:00:12.124: ERROR/ActivityThread(104): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
07-04 00:00:35.335: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(126): ERROR: thread attach failed
07-04 00:00:42.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(211): ERROR: thread attach failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're working on Android, and that you're also referring to the exception in the middle of the log.

The SecurityException means you probably forgot to give the application the necessary permissions - you should change the Manifest XML file, as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html).

Comment: How do I find out what permissions I need. I am yet to see code for a simple program like I wrote with permissions added.

Comment: That really depends on what your program is trying to do.  
Take a loot at the link in my answer and also at this list: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html, which is a comprehensive list of all available permissions in the Android system.

Comment: The program is a calculator for golf handicaps. It has images buttons and button listeners, a few edit text boxes and that is about it. I have not added any thing else yet because it crashes. I looked at the list suggested and do not find any permissions necessary. .java file gets the layout from .xml files and I have not set up the functions yet. Can you think of why the emulator crashes?

Comment: It was a misspelling in an xml file. Thank you for your help. I learned a lot from you. adam.